# Eloquent Collections Where Condition

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to get alternative products pictures.

```
dd($alternativeProduct->pictures);
```

When die and dump i get this result.

[image]

I need to get only the picture which is main. If main equals to 1. It is main picture.

When I write

```
dd($alternativeProduct->pictures->where('main', 1))
```

I got an empty array.

[image]

Here is my relation with Product and Picture relation

```
public function pictures(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\ProductPicture');
}
```

What can i do ?

Comment: Please post the relation you have setup for the pictures in you product model.

Comment: i added the relation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `where` method in a collection has three parameters: `$key`, `$value` and `$strict`, the last one defaults to `true` if not passed when calling the method. When `$strict` is true the comparison is done via `===` which does not do type coercion, meaning `"1" === 1` is false.

From your dump data, I can see that `"main" => "1"` which means it's a string and you're passing an integer `1` to the `where` method, resulting in what I described above as a false condition and returning an empty result set. You can fix that by disabling strict comparison:

```php
$alternativeProduct->pictures->where('main', 1, false);
// or the equivalent helper whereLoose
$alternativeProduct->pictures->whereLoose('main', 1);
```

Or passing a string as the value:

```php
$alternativeProduct->pictures->where('main', "1");
```

---

That being said, if that's the only place you're using that collection in that request's context, I suggest that you filter the results at the database level, not after they are fetched, like so:

```php
$alternativeProduct->pictures()->where('main', 1)->get();
```

Accessing the relations as a method `->pictures()`, instead of as a property `->pictures`, will return a Query Builder instance that allows you to add conditions to the database query and only fetch the actual items you need from the database, instead of fetching them all and filtering them out afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use whereLoose instead:

`dd($alternativeProduct->pictures->whereLoose('main', 1))`

From the Laravel docs:

> The where method uses strict comparisons when checking item values. Use the whereLoose method to filter using "loose" comparisons.